# Adding events more than one on google calendar using batch not working on hosting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-api, google-calendar-api

```js
function sync()
{
 var boardId = $("#hiddenBoardId").val();
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "calendar/getAll",
    data: {boardId:boardId},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (response) {
      //console.log(response);
      var batch = gapi.client.newBatch();
      $.each(response, function(idx, res){
        var startDate = res.startDate;
        var dueDate = res.dueDate;
        var title = res.cardTitle;
        //alert(startDate); //2018-04-12 12:00:00
        var split = startDate.split(" ");
        var split2 = dueDate.split(" ");
        if(startDate != "" && dueDate != "" && dueDate > startDate)
        {
         var event = {
         'summary': title,
         'description': 'Due Date '+title+' from Taff',
         'start': {
        'dateTime': split[0]+'T'+split[1],
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Jakarta'
         },
         'end': {
        'dateTime': split2[0]+'T'+split2[1],
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Jakarta'
         },
         'reminders': {
        'useDefault': false,
        'overrides': [
          {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
          {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}
        ]
         }
       };
       batch.add(gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
           'calendarId': 'primary',
           'resource': event
       }));
       /*var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
         'calendarId': 'primary',
         'resource': event
       });

       request.execute(function(event) {
         appendPre('Event created: ' + event.htmlLink);
       });*/
        }
        else if(dueDate != "" && startDate == "")
        {
         var event = {
         'summary': title,
         'description': 'Due Date '+title+' from Taff',
         'start': {
        'dateTime': split2[0]+'T'+split2[1],
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Jakarta'
         },
         'end': {
        'dateTime': split2[0]+'T'+split2[1],
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Jakarta'
         },
         'reminders': {
        'useDefault': false,
        'overrides': [
          {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
          {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}
        ]
         }
       };
       batch.add(gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
           'calendarId': 'primary',
           'resource': event
       }));
       /*var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
         'calendarId': 'primary',
         'resource': event
       });

       request.execute(function(event) {
         appendPre('Event created: ' + event.htmlLink);
       });*/
        }
        else if(startDate != "" && dueDate == "")
        {
         var event = {
         'summary': title,
         'description': 'Start Date '+title+' from Taff',
         'start': {
        'dateTime': split[0]+'T'+split[1],
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Jakarta'
         },
         'end': {
        'dateTime': split[0]+'T'+split[1],
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Jakarta'
         },
         'reminders': {
        'useDefault': false,
        'overrides': [
          {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
          {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}
        ]
         }
       };
       batch.add(gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
           'calendarId': 'primary',
           'resource': event
       }));
       /*var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
         'calendarId': 'primary',
         'resource': event
       });

       request.execute(function(event) {
         appendPre('Event created: ' + event.htmlLink);
       });*/
        }
       });
       batch.then(function(){
        console.log('all jobs done!!!')
    });
    alert("Done!");
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
   alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}

  // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
  var CLIENT_ID = 'client-id';
  var API_KEY = 'api-key';

  // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
  var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];

  // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
  // included, separated by spaces.
  var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";

  var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
  var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');

  /**
   *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
   */
  function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
  }

  /**
   *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
   *  listeners.
   */
  function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: API_KEY,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      scope: SCOPES
    }).then(function () {
     authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
     authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
     gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
    });
  }

  /**
   *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
   *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
   */
  function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
   if(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()==true)
  {
   //insert();
   sync();
   gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().disconnect();
   //location.reload();
  }
  }

  /**
   *  Sign in the user upon button click.
   */
  function handleAuthClick(event) {
     gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
  }

  /**
   *  Sign out the user upon button click.
   */
  function handleSignoutClick(event) {

  }

  /**
   * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
   * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
   *
   * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
   */
  function appendPre(message) {
    var pre = document.getElementById('content');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
    pre.appendChild(textContent);
  }
```

Im trying to add an event more than one to google calendar

In localhost, i tried using batch and it is working perfectly

But when i moved it to my hosting, it is not working at all.

Im having a non-ssl domain, btw.

it looks like my batch isnt authorized at all, i tried to console.log(batch)
this give a json which give something like this

> {status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", headers: {…}, body: "{↵ "error": {↵  "errors": [↵   {↵    "domain": "gl… "code": 401,↵  "message": "Login Required"↵ }↵}↵", result: {…}}

the question is, do i need to authorized my batch as i already do an authorizing using google calendar?

Alright, this is my solution and my answer.

If you are trying to adding an event on Google Calendar API using Javascript Client that was given from the Quickstart example, the authorization oAuth2 is using API Key. It is only worked on localhost in my opinion.
If you try to add more than 1 events you will need batch, this is an easy option but not working for me on my server.
Instead of javascript, i moved my code to PHP and it is working perfectly. Google Client PHP allows you to get access token so you can add more than one event continously.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error you are getting.

Comment: done, you can check it :)

Comment: Your code isnt authenticating you need to be logged in to run it.

Comment: the ajax function runs after i did a sign in.. can u explain why is my code running in localhost and not in hosting? Thanks

Comment: Either because you have the credentials saved on localhost or because you cant write the credentials on your server.

Comment: I'm sorry i dont really know what to do right now. The json message above is showing me that that user need to login or my app is not verified? Is there any example about using batch on google calendar? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried logging in with the developer who created the project if your not verified yet.  Have you applied for verification?   Where are you seeing that message you have not posted it here.

Comment: yes i have tried to logging in using developer acccount. i dont exactly understand with your verification's mean. The json message is where i got response 401, Unauthorized and Login Required when i tried to console.log(batch). I have copied my full code on the snippet. Thanks if u looked at it. Its pretty dirty. But im pretty hopeless right now. Thank you

Comment: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en

Comment: perhaps thats one of the solution. I have another google API which i used it is Google Picker and Drive. It is showing that my app isn't verified. And i need to click go to domain (unsafe). Will try this and give an update.